# "for each" statement in C++/CLI

Tags: syntax, c++-cli

```
array<int> ^ints = gcnew array<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
for each(int i in ints)
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        Debug::WriteLine("Even\n");
    else
        Debug::WriteLine("Odd\n");
```

Why does the above fail to compile? It works fine if I use a `for(int i; ...)` or if I enclose the `if-else` within braces. I know that the manual clearly indicates that braces are required, but I want to know why this departure from expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any official documentation on it, but I can confirm the behavior you're seeing. It simply appears that the compiler is overly aggressive about finding the single statement following the `for each`, to the point of splitting the `else` from the `if`. It compiles it as if you had written the following, which is clearly incorrect.

```
array<int> ^ints = gcnew array<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
for each(int i in ints)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        Debug::WriteLine("Even\n");
}
else
    Debug::WriteLine("Odd\n");
```

This is obviously different to how a regular C++ `for` loop behaves, so you may wish to file a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not a CLI export but I believe that `for each (i in ints)` is what you are after.</strike>

### Edit

I checked the C++ source that I have available and we are using:

```
for each (int i in ints) {
   // body
}
```

Is it possible that the braces are required? I don't have an MSFT compiler handy or I would try the following:

```
for each (int i in ints) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        Debug::WriteLine("Even\n");
    } else {
        Debug::WriteLine("Odd\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup... sorry... I am too used to other languages.

Comment: Actually, no, it does not introduce another syntax error - it compiles fine for me here using VS2008.

Comment: The code was probably edited to be correct before you tried it :)